# How to center 2 boxes with minipage side by side inside shadowbox

Tags: minipage, fancybox

I have two boxes with `minipage` side by side with different height inside of `\fbox`, and they are centered each other

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.53\textwidth}
text\\[8pt]
text\\[8pt]
text
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.53\textwidth}
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill
\end{minipage}}}}
\end{document}
```

but they are not centered if I use `minipage` inside a `\shadowbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.53\textwidth}
text\\[8pt]
text\\[8pt]
text
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill
\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.53\textwidth}
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill
\end{minipage}}}}
\end{document}
```

How can I center the minipages inside `\shadowbox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-centre the box using `\raisebox`. I also reduced the width a bit to leave room for the shadow as tex was warning about overfull box

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.53\textwidth}
text\\[8pt]
text\\[8pt]
text
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.53\textwidth}
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill
\end{minipage}}}}

\bigskip

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
\raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.52\textwidth}
text\\[8pt]
text\\[8pt]
text
\end{minipage}}}%
\hfill
\raisebox{-.5\totalheight}{\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.52\textwidth}
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill
\end{minipage}}}}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package to easily get any desired vertical alignment:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\parbox{1.2\textwidth}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}%
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.52\textwidth}
text\\[8pt]
text\\[8pt]
text
\end{minipage}}}%
\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\shadowbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.52\textwidth}
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill\\
text \hrulefill
\end{minipage}}}}}
\end{document}
```